# Como funciona a entonação de uma pergunta em português?

Tags: fonemas, perguntas

Para fazer uma pergunta no português falado é preciso mudar a entonação da frase. Isso não acontece em línguas como inglês, que possuem artifícios gramaticais como a inversão do verbo e do sujeito. Por exemplo:

> You like. / Do you like?
>
> Você gosta. / Você gosta?

Na escrita temos o ponto de interrogação, porém na fala temos somente a entonação, já que frases afirmativas e interrogativas são iguais no português.

Existe alguma regra para essa entonação? Foneticamente falando, o que seria a entonação de uma pergunta em português? Tem como fazer uma pergunta sem mudar a entonação, mas utilizando algum artifício gramatical, como no inglês?

Comment: Eu diria que no inglês também há uma entonação típica, apenas não tão realçada como em português.

Comment: Sobre fazer perguntas em português sem entonação, há algumas possibilidades (a partir do contexto sozinho; com gestos; e são claramente perguntas em contextos usuais: "você *teria* um real para me emprestar"; "você tem um irmão, *não*"; etc.), mas normalmente o falante nativo vai usar a entonação de pergunta.

Answer (score 4):

Em se falar da prosódia de frases interrogativas no português, é conveniente dividi-las em algumas classes. Temos:

- Interrogativas totais, onde a interrogação recai sobre a frase inteira, e portanto admite como resposta somente *sim*, *não* ou *talvez* (ou construções equivalentes). Exemplos:

  - *Queres ir ao cinema?*
  - *Você gosta de comer comida japonesa?*
  - *A tia do Antônio melhorou da gripe?*
  - *Eu vou receber alta hoje, doutor?*

  Em todos os casos, a entoação sobe ao longo da frase para chegar a um ápice na última sílaba tônica, podendo ou não haver um pico secundário na sílaba tônica do verbo finito (isto é, aquele que é conjugado para pessoa). Também há de se notar que se houver um vocativo no fim da frase — como no quarto exemplo — o vocativo não é considerado como parte da interrogação: no caso, a sílaba mais aguda seria então o *ho* de *hoje*, não o *tor* de *doutor*.

  Um subtipo das interrogações totais são as interrogações «tag» (*tag questions* em inglês), onde a frase é enunciada como declarativa, e ao final se anexa uma «tag» composta pelo verbo finito com a polaridade invertida, e com a sílaba tônica deste segundo verbo bem mais aguda que o resto da frase:

  - *Você já foi à Bahia, não foi?*
  - *O Juca não chegou a conhecer o avô, chegou?*
- Interrogativas disjuntivas, em que se apresenta uma lista de opções das quais o ouvinte deve selecionar uma. Exemplos:

  - *Você prefere vinho ou cerveja?*
  - *O azul na bandeira da França corresponde à liberdade, à igualdade ou à fraternidade?*
  - *Afinal de contas, tu provaste o camarão ou não provaste?*

  Nestes casos, o tom mais agudo é usado nas sílabas tônicas de cada opção, exceto a da última, que ganha um tom um pouco menos agudo, mas ainda bastante diferente do resto da oração.
- Interrogativas parciais, que são marcadas por um pronome interrogativo, sobre cuja sílaba tônica recai o tom mais agudo da frase. No português, o pronome interrogativo pode ser movido para o princípio da frase, mas não necessariamente. Se houver mais de um pronome interrogativo, somente um pode ser movido. Exemplos:

  - *Queres ir aonde?* ou: *Aonde queres ir?*
  - *Você gosta de comer que tipo de comida?* ou: *Que tipo de comida você gosta de comer?*
  - *Quem melhorou da gripe?*
  - *Eu vou receber alta quando, doutor?* ou *Quando eu vou receber alta, doutor?*

Além desta classificação, pode-se classificar as frases interrogativas como *diretas* ou *indiretas*. Todos os exemplos acima são diretos, onde a interrogação é feita diretamente. Na interrogação indireta, a frase interrogativa se torna uma oração subordinada a uma outra, afirmativa ou negativa; no caso de a interrogação ser total ou disjuntiva, ela é introduzida pela conjunção *se*; no caso de uma interrogação indireta, o pronome interrogativo é deslocado à extremidade esquerda da oração:

- *Não sei se queres ir ao cinema.*
- *Gostava de saber se você gosta de comer comida japonesa.*
- *Você deve saber de que a tia do Antônio melhorou.*
- *Não me disseram quando eu vou receber alta, doutor.*

A prosódia das perguntas indiretas é sempre igual à das frases afirmativas ou negativas que lhes dão apoio. Suponho que este é o máximo de artifício "gramatical" que se pode arranjar para não depender da prosódia para marcar as frases interrogativas; certamente as palavras que marcavam interrogações em latim clássico como *an*, *nonne*, *num* e *-ne* não existem no português moderno.

Fontes:

- [Quais são os tipos de frases interrogativas em português? Ciberdúvidas da Língua Portuguesa.](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/frases-interrogativas-globais-parciais-etc/10652)
- [Couto, L., Silva, C. e Miranda, L. Prosódia de enunciados declarativos e interrogativos totais nas variedades de Salvador, Fortaleza e Rio de Janeiro. *In* **Revista de Estudos da Linguagem**, vol. 25, nº 3. Belo Horizonte, 2017.](http://www.periodicos.letras.ufmg.br/index.php/relin/article/download/11362/pdf)